# Infopath Multiple Selection Checkbox Jumps to the Top

Tags: infopath

I have a multiple selection checkbox control on our InfoPath form with 90+ items to choose from.

When a user scrolls all the way down and selects a checkbox the control
jumps all the way to the top. Basically scrolling all the way up which means
that the user will have to scroll all the way down to select additional
checkboxes.

Why is this happening?